# UnsatisfiedLinkError: ... :findLibrary returned null

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu, android-ndk, java-native-interface

```
03-01 14:00:53.556: E/AndroidRuntime(27208): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load
example from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file 
"/data/app/com.example.test-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.test-
2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
```

I am trying to get a basic environment set up for Android NDK development on Ubuntu 12 and I cannot get this error to go away.  My system is already set up for regular Android development with the SDK.  I've installed the eclipse C/C++ development tools.

My .bashrc has these lines at the bottom:

```
NDK_HOME=~/android-ndk-r9c
export NDK_HOME
export PATH=/home/steve/android-ndk-r9c:${PATH}
export NDK_PATH=/home/steve/android-ndk-r9c
```

In my Eclipse properties, my NDK location in Android->NDK is set to /home/steve/android-ndk-r9c.  My Android.mk looks as follows:

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := test
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := example.c

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

I tried using build-ndk on the command line.  I now have in my project directory a file obj/local/armeabi/libtest.so, but it's not doing me any good.

For what it's worth, no project works, not even the NDK sample projects (such as HelloJni).  What can I do to compile a basic JNI application?

EDIT: This is on an actual device.  The ndk-build output of hello-jni is:

```
[armeabi-v7a] Gdbserver      : [arm-linux-androideabi-4.6] libs/armeabi-v7a/gdbserver
[armeabi-v7a] Gdbsetup       : libs/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup
[armeabi] Gdbserver      : [arm-linux-androideabi-4.6] libs/armeabi/gdbserver
[armeabi] Gdbsetup       : libs/armeabi/gdb.setup
[x86] Gdbserver      : [x86-4.6] libs/x86/gdbserver
[x86] Gdbsetup       : libs/x86/gdb.setup
[mips] Gdbserver      : [mipsel-linux-android-4.6] libs/mips/gdbserver
[mips] Gdbsetup       : libs/mips/gdb.setup
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : hello-jni <= hello-jni.c
[armeabi-v7a] SharedLibrary  : libhello-jni.so
[armeabi-v7a] Install        : libhello-jni.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libhello-jni.so
[armeabi] Compile thumb  : hello-jni <= hello-jni.c
[armeabi] SharedLibrary  : libhello-jni.so
[armeabi] Install        : libhello-jni.so => libs/armeabi/libhello-jni.so
[x86] Compile        : hello-jni <= hello-jni.c
[x86] SharedLibrary  : libhello-jni.so
[x86] Install        : libhello-jni.so => libs/x86/libhello-jni.so
[mips] Compile        : hello-jni <= hello-jni.c
[mips] SharedLibrary  : libhello-jni.so
[mips] Install        : libhello-jni.so => libs/mips/libhello-jni.so
```

Comment: Where are you trying to run the examples? Is it an actual device or an emulator?

Comment: I'm running on an actual device.

Comment: Weird. The error you are experiencing is due to the fact that you do not have any `libtest.so` file in your *libs/* directory. What is the output of the `ndk-build` command for the `hello-jni` project?

Comment: 03-01 15:10:01.675: E/AndroidRuntime(31807): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load hello-jni from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.hellojni-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.hellojni-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null

Comment: That is the Android log output. On your computer, navigate to the *hello-jni/jni* directory, open a console there and execute the `ndk-build` command. Then post here the output of that command.

Comment: My mistake.  I did not read your comment carefully enough.

Comment: As you see, the compilation seems to be just right. It has generated the .so libraries for all the supported platforms: arm, arm-v7, x86, mips. Plus, the *libs/* folder now contains all the .so libraries in the respective directories: so that's correct, too. Could you try running the example now? What IDE are you using?

Comment: I got the same error when I ran it again.  I am running and coding from Eclipse, which is on version Indigo.  Since everything seems correct, where else is it possible that errors may exist?

Comment: It would seem that the generated APK is missing those libraries. What you can do is to export the sample project and generate an APK. Then, open the APK file and check if the .so libraries are still there. If they are, the only possible error that comes to my mind is that the System.loadLibrary() is not working, but I assume that you did not touch any code of the example.

Comment: How do I open an APK to check for libraries?

Comment: If you're using Ubuntu, a double click would suffice. An APK file is just a ZIP file with a different extension.

Comment: well now I feel silly. Anyway all that's in there is a manifest, classes.dex, and resources.arcs

Comment: nevermind, helloJNI DOES work.  I refreshed and everything is working, but I'm still not able to make my test project work.

Comment: Did you check the output of `ndk-build`? Is it correct? Can you post your native library load statement (i.e.: System.loadLibrary(...) )?

Comment: static {
        System.loadLibrary("example");
 }

Comment: aaaaand I've figured it out.  Incredible stupid of me... I was loading the c file name, not the library

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The right way of loading the shared library is

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("test");
}
```

The library name is taken from the `LOCAL_MODULE` definition of your Android.mk file (or from the Application.mk file, if you decide to use it). In your case, you are naming your module **test**. The `ndk-build` generates the shared library `libtest.so`.

Pay attention that you do not need to include the *lib-* prefix in the `System.loadLibrary()` call.

Comment: yup, as soon as you asked to see my load statement I saw the mistake I made.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: Glad I helped you out!